# Warning: StringMap expected string key Use --force to continue

Tags: gruntjs

**`grunt build` command failed with following results**

Please help me....
**NOTE:**
ngAnnotate:dist `reading` happened but after that  `writing` is not happening... 

bower minification is working. controllers,services js files unable to *ngAnnotate*

None of controller have any ES6 features (no arrow funtion ==>, no Let,const keywords used to declare)

my package.json file has below modules

[image]

[image][image: StringMap expected string key Use --force to continue.]

Answer (score 2):

I was using `"grunt-ng-annotate": "1.0.1"` and got the same error. I tried to upgrade but it didn't work.

Since I needed a quick fix, I had to downgrade to `0.10.0` and now it's working fine.

1. I removed the current version: `npm uninstall grunt-ng-annotate --save-dev`
2. And installed the older one: `npm install grunt-ng-annotate@0.10.0 --save-dev`

I hope it helps!